# Randomized vs deterministic approach for multiset equality

Tags: algorithms, randomized-algorithms, polynomials

Let $S_1$ and $S_2$ are two multi sets. We want to find, Is $S_1 =S_2$?

**Algo 1:**

Sort $S_1$ and $S_2$ and then check $S_1 = S_2$

**Running time :** $O(n \log {n})$, where $n$ is the size of the multi sets.

**Algo 2:**

Contruct two polynomials using $S_1$ and $S_2$ (example if $S_1 = \{1,1,2\}$ then polynomial will be $(x-1)(x-1)(x-2)$)

Let us say we have now two polynomials $p(x)$ and $q(x)$, do $p(x)-q(x)$, now using [polynomial identity testing](http://cs.stanford.edu/~mpkim/notes/lec5.pdf) check whether $p(x)-q(x) =0 $ or not. If it is zero then $S_1$ equals to $S_2$.

Question : Which algorithm is better Algo 1 or Algo 2?

Comment: How about defining better? Time wise?

Comment: Time wise but also keeping the model of computation in mind

Comment: How about Algo3: Iterating throug $S_1$ and removing from $S_2$. If an element doesn't exists in $S_2$ or $S_2$ is not empty at the end, then $S_1 \neq{} S_2$. The running time is $O(n)$, if element test and element remove are in $O(1)$.

Comment: BTW.: Algo2 sounds like at least $O(n^2)$ to me, but I haven't proved.

Comment: Where is there randomness here?

Comment: @macmoonshine If we could do that we could sort random permutations in $O(n)$ time (if the set implementation can be created in linear time). So unless we know how the multi-sets are given, this is unlikely to happen.

Comment: @Raphael: Suppose the set implementation is based on hashing, and duplicates are just implemented by counters. This fulfils my restriction to $O(1)$ for testing and removing. Than Algo3 should use $O(n)$, or is there something I don't understand?

Comment: @Raphael Polynomial identity testing is randomized: you substitute a random element and see whether both sides agree.

Comment: Do you have a requirement that set elements are integers?

Comment: yes the elements are integers

Comment: @macmoonshine Hashtables are *not* (worst-case) O(1). Using counters for implementing multi-sets doesn't change that. Of course, since we compare with a probabilistic algorithm, comparing average-case performance might actually be what we're after, but that needs to be made explicit.

Comment: @Raphael: Thanks, I see. Hashsets have only $O(1)$ in average case. Just to avoid a misunderstanding, my hint with the counters was only meant to implement multisets based on hashsets. It is obvious that this does not change the runtime. Your hint to the random permutations is very interesting.

Answer (score 1):

To understand the complexity of the randomized algorithm, you must delve into the implementation details.

Suppose $S_1,S_2$ consist of $m$ elements, each bounded by $n$ in absolute value, i.e. the input size is $O(m\log n)$. Let $P_S=\prod\limits_{w\in s}\left(x-w\right)$ be the polynomial corresponding to the set $S$. $P_{s_1},P_{S_2}$ are degree $m$ polynomials. Thus, in order to succeed with constant probability in testing whether $q(x)=P_{S_1}(x)-P_{S_2}(x)$ is the zero polynomial, you need to evaluate it at numbers in the range $[0,cm]$, for some constant $c$.

Suppose you choose $y$ uniformly at random from this range, then in order to avoid blowup in the intermediate values while computing $q(y)$, you need to compute the values modulo some $k$ (the standard trick in PIT).

Note that the blowup here is not exponential, unlike in PIT where the polynomials are given as algebraic circuits, so you can in fact directly compute $q(y)$. However, this will lead to handling $\Omega(m)$ bit numbers, which will result in quadratic running time, so you can still compute $q(y) \bmod k$ for a random $k$ chosen appropriately to save some time.

If $k$ is chosen at random from some range $[1,R]$, then a "good" event is that $k$ does not divide $q(y)$, in that case $q(y)\neq 0$ iff $q(y) \bmod k \neq 0$. To lower bound this probability, note that $k$ is prime with probability $\approx \frac{1}{\log R}$ (here you need some finite version of the prime number theorem), and that $q(y)\le (cm+n)^m$, hence it has at most $m \log (cm+n)$ different prime factors.

$
\begin{align*}
&
\Pr\limits\left[\text{$k$ is prime $\land$ $k$ is not a product of $q(y)$}\right]=
\Pr\left[\text{$k$ is prime}\right]\cdot\\
&
\Pr\limits\big[\text{$k$ is a product of $q(y)$} \big| \text{$k$ is prime}\big]\approx \frac{1}{\log R}\left(1-\frac{\log (cm+n)^m}{R/\log R}\right)
\end{align*}
$

Choosing $R=(m+n)^2$ suffices to make the above probability high enough, and yields constant success probability after $\approx\log R$ evaluations. Each evaluation requires $O(m)$ additions/multiplications of numbers with $\log R$ bits, thus the overall running time is $O(m\log ^2 R\log\log R)$, which is worse than sorting. Perhaps sharper bounds on the success probability will allow you to get rid of one of the logarithmic factors, but taking numeric operations into account will eventually show that you cant beat naive sorting. However, the randomized approach is not without merits, as it allows you to determine multiset equality between two parties with logarithmic communication (you only need to send $y,k$ and the evaluations of $P_{S_1},P_{S_2}$ on $y$ modulo $k$).